# Стандартные элементы Xcode и Cocos2d

Tags: xcode, разработка-игр, objective-c, cocos2d

Тестовое задание представляет собой приложение из трех View. На каждом из них:

- На первом: UITableView
- На втором: UITextField
- На третьем: Cocos2d Layer

И будет наверно еще один View для меню чтобы переключаться между View.
Прежде практически не работал с Cocos2d. Каким образом можно в рамках одного приложения совместить перемещение между View и Layer'ами?

Comment: Кхм.. Cocos2d Layer в обычном приложении.. интересно. Вообще весь кокосовский функционал крутится во вьюшке OpenGL. Видимо надо рыть в этом направлении. Увы, лично не приходилось это совмешать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже сказал Tuggen, весь кокосовский контент всегда находится внутри одной вьюхи. Так что смело можешь использовать как обычную UIView. Прикрепить к контроллеру или еще что. Код создания OpenGL view можешь глянуть в любом кокосовом template'е.